# Find an element of list based on an element on another list

Tags: python

Suppose we have two  lists `Purchase` and `Product`

```
Purchase = [
     ['James', 'Shoes', 1],
     ['James', 'T-shirt', 3],
     ['James', 'Pants', 2],
     ['James', 'Jacket', 1],
     ['James', 'Bag', 1],
     ['Neil', 'Shoes', 2],
     ['Neil', 'Bag', 1],
     ['Neil', 'Jacket', 1], 
     ['Neil', 'Pants', 1],
     ['Chris', 'Hats', 1],
     ['Chris', 'T-shirt', 2],
     ['Chris', 'Shoes', 1],
     ['Chris', 'Pants', 2],
    ]

Product = [
            ['T-shirt', 110],
            ['Pants', 150],
            ['Shoes', 200],
            ['Hats', 150],
            ['Jacket', 250],
            ['Bag', 230],
            ]
```

On `Purchase`, the first element of every elements is the buyer's name, the second is what product they buy, and the last is how many they buy.
On `Product`, its name of product and its price

What I want to do is to create a new list from a calculation of every buyers purchase for each product and sort it from highest to lowest and take only top 3.
If there's a product are not purchased, it will be multiplied by zero.
For ease of understanding here's the calculation:

```
For 'James':                So the prices from expensive to cheap:
T-shirt -> 110*3 = 330      ['T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket', 'Bag', 'Shoes', 'Hats']
Pants   -> 150*2 = 300
Shoes   -> 200*1 = 200
Hats    -> 150*0 = 0
Jacket  -> 250*1 = 250
Bag     -> 230*1 = 230

For 'Neil':         
T-shirt -> 110*0 = 0        ['Shoes', 'Jacket', 'Bag', 'Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Hats' ]
Pants   -> 150*1 = 150
Shoes   -> 200*2 = 400
Hats    -> 150*0 = 0
Jacket  -> 250*1 = 250
Bag     -> 230*1 = 230

For 'Chris':            
T-shirt -> 110*2 = 220      ['Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes', 'Hats', 'Jacket', 'Bag']
Pants   -> 150*2 = 300
Shoes   -> 200*1 = 200
Hats    -> 150*1 = 150
Jacket  -> 250*0 = 0
Bag     -> 230*0 = 0
```

So in the end this is what I expected:

```
Result  = [
            ['James', 'T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket'],  
            ['Neil', 'Shoes','Jacket', 'Bag'], 
            ['Chris', 'Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes']]
```

Any helps really appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
Result = [[k, *map(itemgetter(1), sorted((-p[i] * c, i) for _, i, c in g)[:3])] for p in (dict(Product),) for k, g in groupby(Purchase, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

With your sample input, `Result` would become:

```
[['James', 'T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket'], ['Neil', 'Shoes', 'Jacket', 'Bag'], ['Chris', 'Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes']]
```

The list comprehension above is simply a more concise version of the equivalent code below:

```
# convert the product pricing into a product-to-price dict for efficient lookup
pricing = dict(Product)
Result = []
# extract the groupings in Purchase based on the first item, the customer's name
for name, purchases in groupby(Purchase, key=itemgetter(0)):
    costs = []
    # for each of a customer's purchases, we calculate the cost by multiplying
    # the product's pricing by the number purchased, and put the calculated cost
    # and product name in a tuple so that it can be sorted by the cost first and
    # then the customer name second; the cost should be negated so to sort
    # in descending order
    for _, product, count in purchases:
        costs.append((-pricing[product] * count, product))
    costs.sort()
    # initialize the sub-list in the output, which starts with the customer's name
    top_products = [name]
    # followed by the top 3 products from the second item in the sorted costs list
    for _, product in costs[:3]:
        top_products.append(product)
    # we've got a finished sub-list to output for the current customer
    Result.append(top_products)
```

Comment: the last line very hard to understand, maybe an explanation will be helpful??

Comment: sorry, really forgot one important things, already edited it the question. My bad

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer accordingly. Still working on the explanations though.

Comment: Just added my explanations in the form of expanded code with in-line comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of approaches, but here's the first that came to mind. I think flatter approaches tend to be a bit easier to understand and maintain than long list comprehensions (though the other answer right now is clever and short).

First, you seem to want to preserve the order the names came in. I think dictionaries are a natural way of dealing with these sorts of linkages, so to preserve sort order I'd personally go for a solution using ordered dictionaries. Additionally, `Product` is much easier to use when you can look things up based on what are effectively keys in a key-value mapping. So, we do the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

Product_kv = dict(Product)
```

From there, we iterate through all the Purchases and maintain a mapping of how much is spent on each item.

```
d = OrderedDict()
for person, item, n in Purchase:
    if person not in d:
        d[person] = {}
    if item not in d[person]:
        d[person][item] = 0
    d[person][item] += n*Product_kv[item]
```

If you had negative counts or prices this would not necessarily be the correct solution. As requested, we can take into account the multiplication by 0 without too much fanfare:

```
for person in d:
    for item in Product_kv:
        if item not in d[person]:
            d[person][item] = 0
```

All that's left is pulling out the sorted data that you want using the pre-computed total expenditures.

```
[[name]+sorted(d[name], key=lambda s:d[name][s], reverse=True)[:3] for name in d]
```

Comment: sorry, really forgot one important things, already edited it the question. My bad

Comment: That's an easy enough change.

Comment: your iteration doesn't doing calculation for products that are not purchased, number off elements in `d` must be same with number of `Product`. Althought is multiplied by zero, it must be included in the dictionary

Comment: the iteration should be doing calculation for products that are not purchased, cheers.

Comment: Try that instead. If the prices/counts are never negative, you'd be better off adding randomly selected products to the lists with fewer than 3 items as a post-processing step. This new change will work regardless though.

Comment: Nice, but two separated iteration seems not efficient. merge it into just one will better

Comment: There are way bigger inefficiencies hiding in that code, notably the use of pure cPython, unnecessary object creation, and doing a full sort when we only care about the 3 biggest elements (especially when we could keep track of those on the fly instead of doing post-processing). That extra looping is negligible in comparison (especially with lots of products), and I think it's easier to read and more maintainable -- arguably the whole reason you used Python in the first place. If the code runs too slowly, optimizing it would be another question with different answers than what you got here.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Python approach would involve dictionaries and explicit iteration. If you're happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# construct dataframe and series mapping
purchases = pd.DataFrame(Purchase)
products = pd.DataFrame(Product).set_index(0)[1]

# calculate value and sort
df = purchases.assign(value=purchases[2]*purchases[1].map(products))\
              .sort_values('value', ascending=False)

# create dictionary or list result
res1 = {k: v[1].iloc[:3].tolist() for k, v in df.groupby(0, sort=False)}
res2 = [[k] + v[1].iloc[:3].tolist() for k, v in df.groupby(0, sort=False)]
```

Result:

```
print(res1)

{'Neil': ['Shoes', 'Jacket', 'Bag'],
 'James': ['T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket'],
 'Chris': ['Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes']}

print(res2)

[['Neil', 'Shoes', 'Jacket', 'Bag'],
 ['James', 'T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket'],
 ['Chris', 'Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use pandas if your application will have to grow and handle many data. This is my version which seems to be very long but I think it is not very difficult to understand by the English function name

```
Purchase = [
     ['James', 'Shoes', 1],
     ['James', 'T-shirt', 3],
     ['James', 'Pants', 2],
     ['James', 'Jacket', 1],
     ['James', 'Bag', 1],
     ['Neil', 'Shoes', 2],
     ['Neil', 'Bag', 1],
     ['Neil', 'Jacket', 1], 
     ['Neil', 'Pants', 1],
     ['Chris', 'Hats', 1],
     ['Chris', 'T-shirt', 2],
     ['Chris', 'Shoes', 1],
     ['Chris', 'Pants', 2],
    ]

Product = [
            ['T-shirt', 110],
            ['Pants', 150],
            ['Shoes', 200],
            ['Hats', 150],
            ['Jacket', 250],
            ['Bag', 230],
            ] 

import pandas as pd

dfPurchase = pd.DataFrame(data=Purchase, columns=['buyer', 'product', 'count'])
print(dfPurchase)
print('\n')

dfProduct = pd.DataFrame(data=Product, columns=['product', 'price'])
print(dfProduct)
print('\n')

dfPurchased = dfPurchase.merge(dfProduct, on='product')
print(dfPurchased)
print('\n')

dfPurchased['priceXcount'] = dfPurchased['price'] * dfPurchased['count']
print(dfPurchased)
print('\n')

lstBuyer = dfPurchased['buyer'].unique()

lstResult = []
for buyer in lstBuyer:
    lstTmp = [buyer]
    dfOneBuyerPurchased = dfPurchased[dfPurchased['buyer'] == buyer]    
    # or you can use:
    # dfOneBuyerPurchased = dfPurchased.query('buyer == "%s"' % buyer)

    lstTmp += dfOneBuyerPurchased.sort_values(
        by='priceXcount', ascending=False
        )['product'].tolist()[:3]

    lstResult.append(lstTmp)

print(lstResult)
```

the output is

```
    buyer  product  count
0   James    Shoes      1
1   James  T-shirt      3
2   James    Pants      2
3   James   Jacket      1
4   James      Bag      1
5    Neil    Shoes      2
6    Neil      Bag      1
7    Neil   Jacket      1
8    Neil    Pants      1
9   Chris     Hats      1
10  Chris  T-shirt      2
11  Chris    Shoes      1
12  Chris    Pants      2


   product  price
0  T-shirt    110
1    Pants    150
2    Shoes    200
3     Hats    150
4   Jacket    250
5      Bag    230


    buyer  product  count  price
0   James    Shoes      1    200
1    Neil    Shoes      2    200
2   Chris    Shoes      1    200
3   James  T-shirt      3    110
4   Chris  T-shirt      2    110
5   James    Pants      2    150
6    Neil    Pants      1    150
7   Chris    Pants      2    150
8   James   Jacket      1    250
9    Neil   Jacket      1    250
10  James      Bag      1    230
11   Neil      Bag      1    230
12  Chris     Hats      1    150


    buyer  product  count  price  priceXcount
0   James    Shoes      1    200          200
1    Neil    Shoes      2    200          400
2   Chris    Shoes      1    200          200
3   James  T-shirt      3    110          330
4   Chris  T-shirt      2    110          220
5   James    Pants      2    150          300
6    Neil    Pants      1    150          150
7   Chris    Pants      2    150          300
8   James   Jacket      1    250          250
9    Neil   Jacket      1    250          250
10  James      Bag      1    230          230
11   Neil      Bag      1    230          230
12  Chris     Hats      1    150          150


[['James', 'T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket'], ['Neil', 'Shoes', 'Jacket', 'Bag'], ['Chris', 'Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas and dictionaries.

```
purch_df = pd.DataFrame(Purchase, columns = ['name','product','count'])
d = dict(Product)
```

Create new column 'price' then perform calculations and save to a new column 'total'

```
purch_df['price'] = [d[product] for product in purch_df['product']]
purch_df['total'] = purch_df['count'] * purch_df['price']
```

Create a dictionary to save grouped dataframes to for future lookup

```
d2 = {}
for group, frame in purch_df.groupby('name'):
    d2[group] = list(frame.sort_values('total', ascending = False).iloc[:3,1])
```

Extract the desired lists from the dictionary d2

```
Result = [lst for _, lst in d2.items()]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dictionary for the `Product` listing as well as the items for each user for an easier lookup:

```
from itertools import groupby
p = dict(Product)
data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in groupby(Purchase, key=lambda x:x[0])]
new_results = [(lambda x, y:[x, [[c, y.get(c, 0)*b] for c, b in p.items()]])(a, dict([h[-2:] for h in b])) for a, b in data]
new_sorted = [[a, *[i[0] for i in sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)][:3]] for a, b in new_results]
```

Output:

```
[['James', 'T-shirt', 'Pants', 'Jacket'], 
 ['Neil', 'Shoes', 'Jacket', 'Bag'], 
 ['Chris', 'Pants', 'T-shirt', 'Shoes']]
```

Comment: maybe an explanation will help :)

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but: Because the code is horribly convoluted and unreadable.